# Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

es la primera vez que tengo la oportunidad de trabajar con api's pero al momento de publicarla en mi PC me sale este error, en Internet dice ser el archivo web.config pero no estoy seguro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi archivo web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ApiExFrog.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 69842ffe-0a80-427c-b4fe-5852a44bec69-->
```

Comment: Puede que tengas algún error de programación. El error 500 indica error de programación. Revisa tu código por algún error de sintaxis.

Comment: Hola. Puedes mostrar la configuración de tu application pool sobre el que se ejecuta tu aplicativo? Seguiste los pasos indicados en [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#application-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el siguiente tag dentro de tu web.config para obtener mas detalle del error. 
`<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>`

Comment: <system.web> <customErrors mode="On" /> </system.web> y con estas líneas donde puede ver al más detalle el error?

Comment: Lo ves al iniciar la aplicación en lugar de mostrarte el error 500 mostraría ademas la posible causa.

Comment: @MaximilianoFlores Utiliza la opción de respuesta solo cuando estés seguro de que se solucionará el problema, para pedir al autor que realice pruebas sobre algo utiliza los comentarios. Puedes leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)